# Apparent Height as a Function of Distance

Tags: geometric-optics

It's no secret that objects that are far away appear smaller than they actually are. Objects that are closer to us appear bigger than they are. Suppose I observe an object a few metres away from me. I take a scale and place it in the same vertical plane as my eye and measure the height of the object. The measurement I take in such a way will be smaller than the measurement taken in the plane of the object itself. My question is this:
Is this "Apparent Height" as a function of distance an exponential function? Is it a linear function? A quadratic function? Or is it a completely different kind of function altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this figure.

[image: Apparent height]

$d$ is the size of the object, $D$ is the distance from you to it.

$d'$ is the size of your rule, and $D'$ its distance to you. So what you call apparent height is $d'$.

If you match the rule to the object, then you get the situation from the figure, with the common angle $\alpha$ (called angular radius). Thales theorem states that $d'/D'=d/D=\tan(\alpha)$.

Since $\alpha$ is fixed for a given object, this gives you the formula to compute $d'$.

Comment: Suppose I place the ruler infinitesimally close to my eye (effectively placing it in the plane of my eye). Would the Apparent Height be zero then?

Comment: It's rather theoretical, but yes.

Comment: I see. Of course, it doesn't make intuitive sense, but a lot of physics doesn't. Thanks for the help.